# Fontspec and Ligatures

Tags: fontspec, ligatures

I understand that if I typeset using `Lualatex` or `Xelatex`, and include the following in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{XYZ}
```

Then system-wide non-latex fonts can be used (substituted for XYZ in the above).

My question is, by using `fontspec`, does this mean that ligatures and kerning, that make LaTeX document otherwise of a higher 'typeset' quality would be essentially discarded for the convenience of getting access to a larger number of fonts?

Does this mean that in the above, one is essentially settling for 2nd best?

Comment: No: a modern opentype font has many ligatures and font shaping possibilities specified within the font. In addition if you also want classic TeX convenience ligatures such as -- to ndash you can use `\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{XYZ}`

Comment: If you choose a font that doesn't have ligatures, you're not going to get ligatures.  See the manual for more information about which ligatures you might want to use *if* the font has them.  What are the other 'subtleties'?

Comment: OpenType font files -- which I assume you're interested in -- generally include detailed kerning tables, and `fontspec` (and a subsidiary package called `luaotfload`) will make use of these tables if they're present. In addition, it is possible to set up so-called "feature files" that override and/or augment the settings shipped with the font family.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A modern opentype font has many ligatures and font shaping possibilities specified within the font. In addition if you also want classic TeX convenience ligatures such as `--` to ndash you can use

```
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{XYZ}
```