# What do the various values of the Ligatures= option of fontspec do?

Tags: xetex, luatex, fontspec, ligatures

The `fontspec` package has a `Ligatures` option, usually encountered with the value `Ligatures=TeX`. This [enables traditional TeX ligatures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/147934/12092) (or typing conventions) like mapping `---` to an em dash. But what does each of the other options do? The [`fontspec` documentation](http://mirror.easyname.at/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/fontspec/fontspec.pdf) only gives a list of the options, without explanation. And the names are not particularly illuminating-- what is the effect of `Ligatures=Logos`, for example? What "common" ligatures does `Ligatures=Common` enable?

I'd like to understand what the options are, and when they are useful/appropriate.

Comment: Note that many of `fontspec`'s options just activate or not features of fonts, if those fonts have them. What they do - if they do anything - depends on the font itself. To know precisely what, you have to inspect the particular font or to just try it. `Ligatures=TeX` is different because it is specially designed to support traditional input of particular characters in the standard TeX way. So this doesn't depend on the font (provided the font has the required characters and is encoded correctly).

Comment: Thanks, I understand that not all features will apply to all fonts. Still, what are these features?

Comment: As @cfr says, that will depend on the font. Which ligatures the `hlig` feature will activate will depend on what ligatures the font in question activates with `hlig`.

Comment: There is no single agreed-upon standard that determines which types of ligatures fall into which category. It's common practice (pun intended) to place some of the `f`-ligatures (e.g., `ff`, `fi`, `fl`, `ffi`, and `ffl`) in the group of "common" ligatures. However, practice among font designers quickly diverges as to how the other f-ligatures (e.g., `ft`, `fft`, `fb`, `ffb`, `fk`, `fr`, etc), let alone other ligatures such as `ct`, `sp`, `st`, etc., should be classified. You'll have to go font by font and figure out which ligatures are provided and how the available ligatures were classified.

Comment: @Mico, thanks, that's the kind of information I was after-- I'm not insisting on iron-cast rules, if there aren't any. If you can think of other recurring option names and what they're likely to do, that would be the answer I'm hoping for.

Comment: PS Could you comment on how one would "figure out what ligatures are provided [by a particular font] and how the available ligatures were classified"? Everyone commenting seems to know where to find this information, but I seem to have missed the memo... (I'm on OS X and I looked in the "Font Book" app: no ligature information.)

Comment: I would use FontForge if you want a graphical interface. You can get some information about the font using `otfinfo`, for example. `otfinfo -f fonts/opentype/public/heuristica/Heuristica-Regular.otf` tells me which features the font provides. But it doesn't tell me what those features do. I'd use FontForge for that.

Comment: Thanks, @cfr! The command line is just fine, but I can try FontForge if it gives more information.

Answer (score 3):

The fontspec package basically just activates certain features available in the font. The options differ depending on what type of font it is.

**For OpenType fonts**

The following table shows which options are available and which features they load (from the latest version of the fontspec package documentation, [fontspec.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/unicodetex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.pdf), 2020/02/21, § 3.1.8 with table 11 on p. 41):

| Option | Tag |
| --- | --- |
| Required | rlig |
| Common | liga |
| Contextual | clig |
| Rare/Discretionary | dlig |
| Historic | hlig |
| TeX | tlig |

What these do in the context of a specific font depends entirely on how the font designer set up that font. I would assume that fonts which make heavy use of such features come with a documentation that explains which ligatures are available and through which feature they are accessible. If not, you can inspect the font yourself using font editing software like FontForge or Glyphsapp (this will require that you can read OpenType feature code instructions).

If you want to know more about the features `rlig`, `liga`, `clig` etc., how they are intended to be used, how they differ from each other etc., you will find that information in the [OpenType spec](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/features_ae) on the Microsoft website.

Note that the option `TeX` above is different from the others, as you already seem to be aware (and user @cfr has also mentioned). A feature `tlig` does not exist in the OpenType spec. This is something TeX-specific to emulate TeX's behaviour for interpreting certain ASCII input.

**For AAT-fonts (Apple)**

For AAT-fonts, fontspec accepts the following `Ligatures` options (§ 3.1 in the documentation):

```
Required, Common, Rare (or Discretionary), Logos, Rebus, Diphthong, Squared,
AbbrevSquared, and Icelandic
```

Some information on what these do is available in the section [Font Feature Registry](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/TrueType-Reference-Manual/RM09/AppendixF.html#Type1) in the AAT specification on Apple Developer. Again, it depends on the individual font what will actually happen when you activate these features. (Some of these are discouraged from use, e.g. `Logos`; `Icelandic` does not seem to be mentioned in the spec).