# Double dash for pages range in acronyms

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I'm using *glossaries* to generate acronyms.
In preable I load the package:

```
\usepackage[toc,acronym]{glossaries} 
\makeglossaries
```

Then I print acronyms:

```
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=Acronyms, style=index]
```

But for the page range of acronyms I get double dash, like that:

[image]

I need one dash only.

Here is an MWE. 
The problem is related to polyglossia and greek language setup.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,draft]{article} 

% setup greek
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainlanguage{greek}
\setotherlanguages{english}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\greekfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\greekfontsf{Times New Roman}

\usepackage[toc,acronym]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newacronym{iss}{ISS}{International Space Station}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=Acronyms, style=index]

\newpage
\gls{iss}
\newpage
\gls{iss}
\newpage
\gls{iss}
\newpage
\gls{iss}
\newpage

\end{document}
```

Comment: What you want is an en-dash, which is what two input hyphens resolves to.  You don't show the input for this page span, and I haven't been successful in trying to copy and paste what is shown, so I can't check to see what is there.  I suspect that there is already a Unicode dash as at least one of the "dashes", so this would be an input coding issue.

Comment: You'll see the same effect when you just type `--` in your document. Normally TeX would turn that into an en-dash. But it doesn't in your setup. Add `[Ligatures=TeX]` to your font definition calls `\newfontfamily\greekfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}` (see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/147934/35864).

Comment: Thank you! ```[Ligatures=TeX]``` was the solution!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same issue can be reproduced in

```
\documentclass[a4paper,draft]{article}

% setup greek
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainlanguage{greek}
\setotherlanguages{english}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\greekfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\greekfontsf{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}
Lorem -- ipsum
\end{document}
```

when compiled with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX that MWE produces

[image: Lorem -- ipsum]

The underlying issue here is that traditionally the en-dash is produced by a ligature of two hyphens `--` in TeX.

But in the fonts loaded with `fontspec` that is not usually the case (if you type `--` with those fonts in other programs [that don't apply automatic substitutions], you really get just `--`).

`fontspec` allows users to access these traditional TeX ligatures with the font option `Ligatures=TeX` (as far as I understand these ligatures are not implemented as ligatures at the font level but via other means). The option `Ligatures=TeX` is automatically applied for `\setmainfont`, `\setsansfont` and `\setmonofont`, but not for fonts defined via `\newfontfamily`.

So you can resolve the issue by explicitly selecting `Ligatures=TeX` in `\newfontfamily`

```
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}
```

In the MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,draft]{article}

% setup greek
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainlanguage{greek}
\setotherlanguages{english}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}

\usepackage[toc,acronym]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newacronym{iss}{ISS}{International Space Station}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

Lorem -- ipsum

\newpage
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=Acronyms, style=index]

\newpage
\gls{iss}
\newpage
\gls{iss}
\newpage
\gls{iss}
\newpage
\gls{iss}
\newpage

\end{document}
```

[image: ISS International Space Station. 3–6]

See also [Fontspec and Ligatures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/147934/35864).